# UIWebView scalesPageToFit property, what is it actually doing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uikit

`UIWebView` has a property called [scalesPageToFit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scalesPageToFit), which can be set to `YES` or `NO`.

I was wondering if anyone had an explanation as to what it actually does with regards to how it works. What criteria is it looking at when it scales the page? Is it looking for the widest table or div and then zooming out to fit that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- So far to my knowledge when you set scalesPageToFit to YES it will show the content within the Webview space.
- Then you can zoom out to see the content according to the users capability of reading.
- I have done this a few times for pdf file, so it will show the pdf content within the content width. Actually it will scale it proportionally.

Comment: Yes, I understood what it does, what I'm wondering how it determines what the right scale is